# Caching authentication result in django-rest-framework-jwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, auth0, django-rest-framework-jwt

I`m using Auth0 authentification in a webapp / django-server combination. Auth0 is not the fastest auth framework, it always takes 200ms to authenticate. My webapp sends a lot of requests to the django server, so I thought about caching the authentication for a few seconds. This improves the speed of my app a lot.

Is this a good way? Do you see any disadvantages / security issues in doing it this way?

django config:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    (...)

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        (...)
        'rg_auth.rest_framework_authentication_classes.RgJSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        (...)
    ),

    (...)
}
```

authentication class:

```
import hashlib

from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.authentication import get_authorization_header
from django.core.cache import cache

class RgJSONWebTokenAuthentication(JSONWebTokenAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        # Get from cache
        cache_key = self._rg_get_cache_key(request)        
        cached_user_payload_tuple = cache.get(cache_key)

        # Is cache set?
        if cached_user_payload_tuple:            

            # Cache is set: Return user/payload tuple
            return cached_user_payload_tuple

        else:

            # Cache is not set: Authenticate and save tuple to cache for 10 seconds
            user_payload_tuple = super().authenticate(request)

            if user_payload_tuple:
                # Set cache
                cache.set(cache_key, user_payload_tuple, 10)           

                # Return tuple
                return user_payload_tuple    

    def _rg_get_cache_key(self, request):
        auth_header = get_authorization_header(request)        
        auth_header_md5 = hashlib.md5(auth_header).hexdigest()
        return "RgJSONWebTokenAuthentication_{}".format(auth_header_md5)
```

Comment: Did you implement this? Any findings? I'm considering similar.

Comment: It`s running since two years in a production system with load of 500.000 requests / month and I had no problems 